# Lyx captions: some captions wrong language in PDF, DVI but right language in Lyx-HTML

Tags: lyx, captions, languages

*System and document settings*: kubuntu 16.04, LyX 2.1.4. In the *document settings* the language is set to English.

*Problem*: The captions for "propositions" and "references" appear in German when compiling to both PDF and DVI (they shouldn't) **but** appear in English (as they are supposed to) when compiling to LyXHTML.

*Cause of problem*: By mistake, the language of the label of the first enumerated line in the "minimum working example" below  has been set to German. (Removing the line removes also the problem. To find it rapidly search for the phrase "Probably" in the text.)

Question: Is this a bug or a latex coding mistake?

*Minimum working example*:

```
#LyX 2.1 created this file. For more info see http://www.lyx.org/
\lyxformat 474
\begin_document
\begin_header
\textclass article
\begin_preamble
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000
\end_preamble
\use_default_options true
\begin_modules
natbibapa
theorems-ams-bytype
theorems-ams-extended-bytype
enumitem
linguistics
\end_modules
\maintain_unincluded_children false
\language english
\language_package auto
\inputencoding auto
\fontencoding global
\font_roman times
\font_sans lmss
\font_typewriter default
\font_math auto
\font_default_family default
\use_non_tex_fonts false
\font_sc false
\font_osf false
\font_sf_scale 100
\font_tt_scale 100
\graphics default
\default_output_format default
\output_sync 0
\bibtex_command bibtex
\index_command default
\paperfontsize 12
\spacing onehalf
\use_hyperref true
\pdf_bookmarks true
\pdf_bookmarksnumbered false
\pdf_bookmarksopen false
\pdf_bookmarksopenlevel 1
\pdf_breaklinks false
\pdf_pdfborder false
\pdf_colorlinks false
\pdf_backref false
\pdf_pdfusetitle true
\papersize default
\use_geometry false
\use_package amsmath 1
\use_package amssymb 1
\use_package cancel 1
\use_package esint 1
\use_package mathdots 1
\use_package mathtools 1
\use_package mhchem 1
\use_package stackrel 1
\use_package stmaryrd 1
\use_package undertilde 1
\cite_engine natbib
\cite_engine_type authoryear
\biblio_style plainnat
\use_bibtopic false
\use_indices false
\paperorientation portrait
\suppress_date false
\justification true
\use_refstyle 1
\notefontcolor #0a12ad
\index Index
\shortcut idx
\color #008000
\end_index
\secnumdepth 0
\tocdepth 1
\paragraph_separation skip
\defskip medskip
\quotes_language english
\papercolumns 1
\papersides 1
\paperpagestyle default
\tracking_changes false
\output_changes false
\html_math_output 0
\html_css_as_file 0
\html_be_strict false
\end_header

\begin_body

\begin_layout Title
Why are the proposition and references captions in German? 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Date
Working paper, 11-8-2016
\end_layout

\begin_layout Author
Will
\begin_inset Newline newline
\end_inset

New in the Stackexchange Community
\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
Hey, it's snowing outside.
 How nice.

\begin_inset Newpage clearpage
\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Abstract
\begin_inset CommandInset toc
LatexCommand tableofcontents

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Introduction
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Hey, it's snowing outside.
 How nice
\begin_inset CommandInset citation
LatexCommand citep
after "p. 1"
key "schwartz1992universals"

\end_inset

.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Method
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Put your snow-boots on and lets go.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Enumerate

\lang ngerman
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "enu:unv"

\end_inset


\begin_inset Argument 1
status collapsed

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\lang ngerman
\begin_inset ERT
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

label=
\backslash
Alph{enumi})
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset


\lang english

\begin_inset Flex URL
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
<< Probably this enumerated line is causing the problem: By mistake the
 label has been set to German.
 It seems to cause the wrong language setting problem, since it can be solved
 by removing this line.
 >> 
\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Enumerate
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "enu:volunteerinternational"

\end_inset


\begin_inset Flex URL
status open

\begin_layout Plain Layout

http://tex.stackexchange.com
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
Lore ispum.

\end_layout

\end_deeper
\begin_layout Standard
Put your snow-boots on and lets go.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Results
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Very nice outside.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Quotation
Yep, nice.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Conclusions
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Welcome winter.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Proposition
Every winter is a winter.
\end_layout

\begin_layout --Separator--

\end_layout

\begin_layout Proposition
No winter is a summer.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Section
Acknowledgments 
\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
Many thanks to the Tex StackExchange Community.

\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\begin_inset CommandInset bibtex
LatexCommand bibtex
bibfiles "../../../Literatur.Datenbank/Lyx-Bibliographien/Die-üblichen-Quellen"
options "apa"

\end_inset


\end_layout

\begin_layout Standard
\start_of_appendix
\begin_inset Tabular
<lyxtabular version="3" rows="20" columns="3">
<features rotate="0" booktabs="true" islongtable="true" headBottomDL="true" longtabularalignment="center">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="6text%">
<column alignment="center" valignment="top" width="10text%">
<column alignment="left" valignment="top" width="75text%">
<row endhead="true">
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
Nice, empty.

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" leftline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
<row caption="true">
<cell multicolumn="1" alignment="center" valignment="top" usebox="none" width="91text%">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset Caption Standard

\begin_layout Plain Layout
\begin_inset CommandInset label
LatexCommand label
name "tab:Data-sources"

\end_inset

Data sources
\end_layout

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="center" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
<cell multicolumn="2" alignment="left" valignment="top" topline="true" bottomline="true" usebox="none">
\begin_inset Text

\begin_layout Plain Layout

\end_layout

\end_inset
</cell>
</row>
</lyxtabular>

\end_inset


\end_layout

\end_body
\end_document
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: @Will can you please post a .lyx file as a minimal example (you can just paste the text as code since a .lyx file is just a text file)? This way we can figure out if it is a LyX bug. For more information, see https://wiki.lyx.org/FAQ/MinimalExample